# How do I sort records which are like `a | b | c | 8` and `n | 8 | p | 4` in Python?

Tags: python, sorting, csv

I have a CSV file containing values like `a | b | c | 8` and `n | 8 | p | 4` as so on. I would like to know as to how do I sort them considering the last element in each row as the index?

Ex: sorted order for the above would be `n | 8 | p | 4` and `a | b | c | 8`

I am using Python csv reader to read the file and want to apply Quick sort. I split the CSV with `'|'` but not quite sure how do I proceed from here. Or if splitting isn't the correct thing to do? Can someone shed some light as to how I should be doing it?

Comment: How often do you need to do this? How many other manipulations with table data like this will you be doing? Because it might be practical to install the [pandas package](http://pandas.pydata.org/) and use that.

Comment: If you're on a *nix command line, a simple `sort -k4 -t'|'  input_file.csv` would do the trick, btw.

Comment: @Evert The idea is to sort these records on a regular basis since there will be a lot more records pumped into the csv regularly. (Usually around 10 - 20 times a day) Once I have these records sorted, I need to be applying other small operations which isn't all that resource intensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a list of lists you could use the pre built sorting function,
which should be faster than anything you can implement yourself.

There is a command in sort which then does exactly what you want:

```
sorted(yourArray, key=lambda x: x[3])
#sort yourArray by the 4th value in every list
```

So what I would do is:

- Read csv and split it with ' | '
- Save all lines you read in a list
- use the above function which **returns a new list** (it is not in place sorting)

**Edit**

Just saw the new comments, and if you want to add new entries and keep your List sorted, you should look into the [bisec module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#module-bisect).

It is used for inserting values into an already sorted list, but does not support the `key` operator.
They explain how to use it for lists of your type in the last paragraph of the link.